# Publishing rate of gazebo sensor plugins broken on fuerte?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, gazebo-plugins, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

it looks to me like the publish rate of sensors in the currently installed gazebo version from .debs (1.4.15-s1338549736~oneiric) is broken. For instance, if I start the hector quadrotor indoor SLAM demo using

```
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch
```

on electric, I get:

```
stefan@SKdell:~$ rostopic hz /scan
subscribed to [/scan]
average rate: 40.052
    min: 0.000s max: 0.046s std dev: 0.01142s window: 32
average rate: 40.000
    min: 0.000s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.01219s window: 68
average rate: 40.000
    min: 0.000s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.01249s window: 101
^Caverage rate: 40.012
    min: 0.000s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.01245s window: 134
```

The scans are published at a rate of 40Hz, as intended. If I do exactly the same on fuerte (with the updated stack for fuerte, but the urdf and plugin settings are the same), I get this:

```
stefan@SKdell:~$ rostopic hz scan
subscribed to [/scan]
average rate: 12.923
    min: 0.000s max: 0.166s std dev: 0.04591s window: 30
average rate: 12.276
    min: 0.000s max: 0.243s std dev: 0.05389s window: 60
average rate: 12.182
    min: 0.000s max: 0.243s std dev: 0.05367s window: 90
average rate: 12.599
    min: 0.000s max: 0.243s std dev: 0.05274s window: 120
```

The LIDAR is mounted to the quadrotor in [quadrotor_hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/fuerte/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_urdf/urdf/quadrotor_hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro), using the [hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/fuerte/hector_models/hector_sensors_description/urdf/hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro) macro. It appears the gazebo plugin settings there are read correctly, but the update rate is off. Note that "use_sim_time" is set correctly on the parameter server. Simulated SLAM also works fine on electric, but basically not at all on fuerte currently.

I observed similar problems with camera plugins publishing at a too low rate, making this a very severe problem. Any explanations/suggestions (also as to where to put a ticket ;) Trac or bitbucket ) would be helpful.

/edit: Also tested using the simulated Kinect on the Turtlebot, same story:

Electric:

```
stefan@SKdell:~$ rostopic hz /camera/depth/points
subscribed to [/camera/depth/points]
average rate: 20.000
    min: 0.050s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00000s window: 8
average rate: 20.000
    min: 0.050s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00000s window: 18
average rate: 20.000
    min: 0.050s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00000s window: 28
average rate: 20.000
    min: 0.050s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00000s window: 38
average rate: 20.000
    min: 0.050s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00000s window: 48
```

Fuerte:

```
stefan@SKdell:~$ rostopic hz /camera/depth/points
subscribed to [/camera/depth/points]
average rate: 12.195
    min: 0.082s max: 0.082s std dev: 0.00000s window: 2
average rate: 8.746
    min: 0.082s max: 0.148s std dev: 0.02696s window: 4
average rate: 7.767
    min: 0.082s max: 0.172s std dev: 0.03419s window: 5
average rate: 7.830
    min: 0.082s max: 0.172s std dev: 0.02803s window: 8
average rate: 7.484
    min: 0.082s max: 0.175s std dev: 0.03053s window: 9
average rate: 7.931
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43960/publishing-rate-of-gazebo-sensor-plugins-broken-on-fuerte?/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-18**:
I hope this question can help the trouble shooting.... Is the output "consistent" over time, i.e. if you run "rostopic hz" and then cancel it and run it again, do you observe the same min, max and std deviation?  (I noticed in-run consistency, but between-run inconsistency).

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-09-18**:
Yes the output always has the same qualitative difference (close to desired update rate with electric, no jitter vs. far below desired update rate with fuerte - high jitter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry, this must have fallen off the treadmill at some point.  I took a brief look, and `SensorManager::Update()` inlines image rendering update with the laser sensor update.  I think splitting up the two updates into separate thereads should solve this issue.

See [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/20/laser-scan-ray-sensor-updates-erratic-and).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1